# Images inside my Search Result web part will have their names = DispForm.aspx

Tags: 2013, development, search-results, display-template, search-results-webpart

I am working on team sub-site inside my sharepoint on-premises farm 2013. now i define the following criteria to show all the items inside a document library:-

```
{searchboxquery}

 Path:"http://w*****/*****/******/Shared Documents/"
 EditableByOtherOWSCHCS=Yes
```

[image]

now i have noted that if i have images with the following extensions `.png` or `.gif` or  `.jpg`. then they will have the following Names `DispForm.aspx` inside the search results, while the title will be correct, as follow:-

[image]

Although if i chose to display the item properties i will get the correct names and title something as follow:-

[image]

now inside the display template i am using the following managed properties:-

- For the Name = `FileName`
- For the Title = `Title`

as follow:-

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'ListID','ListItemID','ContentTypeId','Link URL':'Path','CommentOWSMTXT','BodyOWSMTXT','Property 1':'FileName','Property 2':'Title'./*other properties goes here...*/..</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
```

so what could be the reason that the Names for the images specifically is being shown as `DispForm.aspx` ??

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that the item is being handled as a specific file type rather than as a list item in a library.

There are specific instructions [here](http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-image-preview-in-search.html), but basically:

1. Go to Central Admin > Search Service Application
2. File Types > New File Type.
3. Enter an image type/types you want to handle with this rule (repeat as necessary)
4. Go back to the searched library/list's list settings
5. Go to Advanced settings and reindex it.
6. Kick off the search crawl.

If you want more specific behavior than just an image in the search results, you'll need to create a new/edit an existing display template.

Comment: ok will try you steps.. but is there a specific reason why sharepoint does not add these types "gif", "jpg", "png" inside the search service by defualt ?

Comment: It's one of those things where not all groups want to make their farms image friendly. You may have a search where you only want full content coming back based on the term rather an image that has that term in the name or some part of it's data. 

I've also had some farms where we had professional documents in the same site as employee cookout photos that I wouldn't want seen in a search for a related term.

Also, Microsoft. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: now should i re-index the related libraries one by one? as in my case i did an index reset from the central administration, then i run a full crawl.. but still i am seeing the images have Dispform.aspx as their names inside the search result web part..

Comment: now i reindex the document library and i also i did an index reset for the whole search service ,then i run a full crawl, but still the images will have Dispform.aspx as their names !!!

Comment: It should be a reindex on the library itself first. I'm sure there's powershell script if you wanted to force it and there are background processes that handle indexing if you feel like waiting long enough for that to kick it. If that's still not taking you may have to edit the display template.

Comment: yes I did a reindex for the whole document library and reindex for the whole search service.. but still I did not get any thing changed..now u r saying to edit the display template .. but what I need to change inside it ???

Comment: can you advice more on this?

Comment: Check out the link in the answer. The second step on creating a custom display template should allow you to handle image files exactly as you want.

Answer (score 2):

I POC'd this for you in SharePoint Online tonight, but using a 2013 Search Center. Results could vary based on on-premises vs Online, but I'm hopeful this information will provide the answer you're looking for.

Unfortunately the OOB managed property you'd expect to work (Path) is always going to point to the DispForm.aspx, since it's not indexing the image file itself.

You'll also see that another OOB managed property (FileType) will show you things like 'JPG', but you still won't have your file reference. What you need is 'Filename', which is the reference to the file within its parent (it won't include the full path, just the file name and extension)

I'd be happy to look at your display template in more detail, but I'm wondering if there's a formatting issue in there (since I see you're trying to use Filename, which is correct, but you're still getting DispForm.aspx).

I added 'Filename':'Filename' to the end of my display template's ManagedPropertyMapping tag (item_default.html), and when I went in to debug the results (targeting item_default.js in Chrome), you'll see in the below screenshot that it indeed does return the correct filename for that property.

Updated ManagedPropertyMapping
[image: Display Template with Filename]

Debug results with the correct filename showing
[image]

I hope that this information helps solve your problem, and again, feel free to reach out to me directly if you're still having issues, and would like a second set of eyes on your display template and/or debugging session.

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: first point before providing further details ... can u please advice where you find that i am using  `Filename` as you are mentioning??? in my display template i am using FileName as follow `'Property 1':'FileName'`.. second point it might worth mentioning that the display template i am using will show documents from document libraries,, and those documents can be pdf, word, excel, etc... now for all the file types i will get the correct Name & Title.. so the managed properties i am using should be fine.. since i am able to retrieve the correct values for files other than the images..

Comment: Yeah - it should be Filename, not FileName. That format 'Value': 'Value' essentially means you'll have properties off CurrentItem mapped to the names of managed properties after the colon (multiple values can be separated with semi-colon), and then you can use what comes before the colon inside of $getItemValue(ctx,'Value'). Can you change 'Property 1':'FileName' to 'Filename':'Filename', and then debug and confirm that your ctx.CurrentItem.Filename is correct? You should get the same thing when you debug with $getItemValue(ctx,'Filename').

Comment: Also, regarding your question about other file types working, that's because SP is indexing their actual content (pdf, docx, etc..). It's not indexing into the images, but Filename is an easy way to get a link directly to the image. Cheers.

Comment: Have any updates after trying the above listed in the comments, John?

Comment: sorry i did not get your point on this `Can you change 'Property 1':'FileName' to 'Filename':'Filename',` ??Now i need to specify "Property 1" so it will be shown as the first column inside my display template... now you also mentioned that you have added 'Filename':'Filename' to the end of your display template's ManagedPropertyMapping tag,, so you did not actually changed `Property 1':'FileName' to 'Filename':'Filename',` but you place it at the end of the ManagedPropertyMapping tag?? is this correct?

Comment: Jimision can u please advice on my above comment?

Comment: Can you share your entire managedpropertymapping? I want you to change the part referencing Filename.

Comment: Would love to help you resolve this before the bounty ends tomorrow. I was just asking you to change your managed properties, and then have you debug, to confirm the ctx.CurrentItem had the correct Filename.

Comment: appreciate your help on this ,, do not worry the boundary can still be granted to existing answers if it expires -as per my knowledge-, if not i can add a new boundary ... as i need to get this fixed.. now here is my full managedpropertymapping

Comment: `<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'ListID','ListItemID','ContentTypeId','Link URL':'Path','CommentOWSMTXT','BodyOWSMTXT','Property 1':'FileName','Property 2':'','Property 3':'Title','Property 4:'ITDocumentCategoryOWSCHCS','Property 5':'ITSecurityOWSCHCS','Property 6':'EditableOWSCHCS','Property 7':'LastModifiedTime','Property 8':'EditorOWSUSER','Property 9':'','Property 10':'','FileExtension','SecondaryFileExtension'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>`

Comment: Ok, change it to the below:
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'ListID','ListItemID','ContentTypeId','Link URL':'Path','CommentOWSMTXT','BodyOWSMTXT','Filename':'Filename','Property 2':'','Property 3':'Title','Property 4:'ITDocumentCategoryOWSCHCS','Property 5':'ITSecurityOWSCHCS','Property 6':'EditableOWSCHCS','Property 7':'LastModifiedTime','Property 8':'EditorOWSUSER','Property 9':'','Property 10':'','FileExtension','SecondaryFileExtension'</mso:Managed‌​PropertyMapping>

Comment: After you change it, use your browser dev tools to debug on your display template js file, and examine ctx.CurrentItem.Filename . You should find that on the images, you now see the filename.

Comment: i did not get ur point on this ? so why you removed the `Property 1`?? and is this for testing or it should work ? as the way i understand display templates,, is that it will use Property 1 to show it as the first column inside the result.. is this correct?

Comment: Check out my first comment where I explained the naming convention. To make your change simpler, though, just take your current settings and only change FileName to Filename and then use ctx.CurrentItem.Filename to get the value you are looking for.